# (Polymer) Custom Element lifecycle hook after style and layout

Tags: polymer, web-component

I need to know where on the page my element is when my element gets initialized. I tried using connectedCallback

`connectedCallback(){
    console.log(this.$.someDiv.getBoundingClientRect())
}`

but it gives me `{top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, width: 0…}`, apparently because when `connectedCallback` is called, layout hasn't happened yet. When I go in with dev tools, `$0.$.someDiv.getBoundingClientRect()` gives me the correct values (e.g. in this case `{top: 154.59375, right: 614, bottom: 634.59375, left: 54, width: 560…}`)

Is there any lifecycle hook or event or something that I can use to get this information after layout has been calculated? I don't want to have to use SetTimeout and just hope it works...

Comment: did you try it in the `ready` method of your element

Comment: @jeanPoku I originally had in in `ready()` but that didn't work. According to the polymer docs, `The first **attached** callback is guaranteed not to fire until after **ready**.` (for polymer 2.0 `attached` is called `connectedCallback`)